# How can I properly use '$(this)' to call a DOM element that triggered the event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote the following script that resets the the Iframe Source, removes a class (.play) and adds an image placeholder when .b-close is clicked. I got it to work but the problem is that I have multiple modals and I would like only like to affect the modal that's clicked. I figured that I should use the '$(this)' DOM element in order to achieve this.

```
<script>

  (function($){

  var ivid = $('.pretty-embed iframe').attr('src'); 

    $(document).ready(function() {

          $(".b-close").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var vidID = $(this).parent().find('.pretty-embed').attr('data-pe-videoid');
          var vidImg = "//img.youtube.com/vi/"+vidID+"/maxresdefault.jpg";
          var vidImgUrl = '<img src="'+vidImg+'" width="100%" alt="YouTube Video Preview">';
          $('.pretty-embed').removeClass('play').empty();
          $('.pretty-embed').html(vidImgUrl);
          $('.b-modal').click(); /// Just trying to close modal..... $.modal.close();
     });
   });

 })(jQuery);

</script>
```

Here's is the the Modal that I will be calling. Keep in mind that there will be multiple modals, so I would only like to affect the modal that's clicked

```
<div id="element_to_pop_up" display: block;">
    <a class="b-close">x</a>
    <h3 class="pop-hd">Header</h3>
     <p>Test Video</p>
     <div class="pretty-embed play" data-pe-allow-fullscreen="false">
     <iframe width="330" height="186" style="border:none;" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/nGSfaMxCu-U?autoplay=1&amp;rel=1"></iframe>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What plugin are you using for the Modal dialog?

Comment: That HTML is invalid :-(

Comment: the `e` event also contains a pointer to the DOM node that the event was triggered by. e.g. for a click, that'd be the dom element you clicked on. since that's just a dom node, you wander around the DOM tree from that point to find the nodes you want to manipulate.

Comment: You already did it once, `$(this).parent().find('.pretty-embed')` why didn't you continue with that trend through the rest of the code?

Comment: @silkfire l'm using Pretty Embed, it's a wordpress plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `$('.pretty-embed')` selector which selects all the embed elements in all modals If I understood your problem correctly. To fix that take the id of the modal and prepend it to the selectors like below:

```
(function($){

   var ivid = $('.pretty-embed iframe').attr('src'); 

   $(document).ready(function() {

      $(".b-close").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var vidID = $(this).parent().find('.pretty-embed').attr('data-pe-videoid');
      var vidImg = "//img.youtube.com/vi/"+vidID+"/maxresdefault.jpg";
      var vidImgUrl = '<img src="'+vidImg+'" width="100%" alt="YouTube Video Preview">';
      var parent_id = $(this).parent().attr(id);
      // Prepend the parent id before the .pretty-embed selector
      $('#'+parent_id+' .pretty-embed').removeClass('play').empty();
      $('#'+parent_id+' .pretty-embed').html(vidImgUrl);
      $('#'+parent_id+' .b-modal').click(); /// Just trying to close modal... $.modal.close();
    });
});
```

Also you can use the same way you did it in the previous lines:

```
$(this).parent().find('.pretty-embed').removeClass('play').empty();
```

Comment: @Jimmy You're welcome. I updated the answer. If it solved your problem please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current modal with

```
var current_modal = $(this).parent().find('.pretty-embed');
```

Then remove the class `play`, and add your image like this:

```
current_modal.removeClass('play').empty();
current_modal.html(vidImgUrl);
```

See your complete code in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ackd59b0/)